# Why it takes value instead column name in sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jsp

I am trying to add a new row to my sql table from an jsp file. For this, I used preparedStatement but while executing the statement, sql server takes the entered value as column name.

Here is my related code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XYZ Web Application | Creating New User Account</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection connection = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1; 
databaseName=UserRecords; " +
                "username=name; password=password");

        Statement statement1 = connection.createStatement();
        if(statement1.executeQuery("select * from Users where username = " + 
username + " or email = " + email) != null){
            out.println("The username or email that you entered is already 
exist");
        }else{
            PreparedStatement statement = 
connection.prepareStatement("insert into UserRecords.Users (username, 
password, email) values(?,?,?)");
            statement.setString(1, username);
            statement.setString(2, password);
            statement.setString(3, email);

            statement.executeUpdate();
            out.println("Your account has been created. Go back to the home 
page to login.");
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        out.println("New user could not be created ..!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

%>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/UserInterfaces/Welcome.jsp" 
target="_blank">Home</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is sql server takes entered value as column name so it returns `invalid column name 'entered value'` as I mentioned above. For example if user types "myusername", it returns `invalid column name 'myusername'`
 Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you better explain what the problem is?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated the question.

Comment: Please do **NOT** put connection handling and SQL statements into a JSP page. Create a servlet that provides the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your string literals with single quotes.  The error is being caused by your database interpreting those string literals as column names, which is not what you intend.  I will address the select query.  Here is what the raw query should look like:

```
select *
from Users
where username = 'username' or email = 'email';
```

You *could* technically add single quotes in your concatenated string.  But that approach is error prone as you have seen, and also opens your application to SQL injection attacks.  Probably the best approach for you would be to use *prepared* statements.  Here is how you would handle the above select query using prepared statements:

```
String sql = "select * from Users where username = ? or email = ?;";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, email);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String uname = rs.getString("username");
    String em = rs.getString("email");
}
```

Comment: I had been tried the above code while implementing sign in part of my web application and it worked well. But my problem is not with the select query. I am troubling with insert, and I could not get where to put single quote in my code. You mean like '?' this, can you give an example please. Thanks.

Comment: @JollyRoger Your insert looks fine; I see you are already using a prepared statement there.  Your error output is consistent with the select which I have corrected, not the insert.